# Java validate SMTP server using telnet

Tags: java, performance, smtp, telnet, email-bounces

i'm using a library for validating SMTP connection to test invalid mail domains to avoid sending mails and bounce, simply i'm using telnet to simulate `MAIL FROM: <{Address}>` and `RCPT TO: <{Address}>` using `BufferedWriter` and `BufferedReader` as follows:

```
    private static void send(BufferedWriter wr, String text)
        throws IOException {
    wr.write(text + "\r\n");
    wr.flush();
    return;
}

    private static int receive(BufferedReader in) throws IOException {
    String line = null;
    int eCode = 0;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        String pfx = line.substring(0, 3);
        try {
            eCode = Integer.parseInt(pfx);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            eCode = -1;
        }
        if (line.charAt(3) != '-') break;
    }
    return eCode;
}
```

calling just as follows:

```
 Socket skt = new Socket("gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com", 25);
 BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream()));
 BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(skt.getOutputStream()));
 send(bufferedWriter, "MAIL FROM: <{Address}>");
 int status = receive(bufferedReader);
 send(bufferedWriter, "RCPT TO: <{Address}>");
 status = receive(bufferedReader);
```

the only problem i'm facing with this approach is performance, as `MAIL FROM` CMD typically takes **10** sec and `RCPT TO` CMD takes **20** sec (**on terminal**)
which is too much, is there's an idea of how to do that fast or use another mechanism to achieve that correctly in 1 or 2 seconds maximum ?